# NoMethodError: undefined method 'each' for string when deploying using Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

New to RoR and deploying my first app on a Digital Ocean droplet using Ubuntu with Capistrano, Nginx, and Puma.

After entering the command for the first deployment, I get a message, "rake stdout: rake aborted! NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for #".

I've been searching StackOverflow and other forums to troubleshoot but no luck.

cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host xx.xx.xx.xx: Exception while executing on host xx.xx.xx.xx: rake exit status: 1
rake stdout: rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for #<String:0x00000003f09ee0>
/home/deploy/apps/lcv011/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:150:in`resolve_all'
/home/deploy/apps/lcv011/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:69:in `resolve'
/home/deploy/apps/lcv011/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/core.rb:46:in`configurations='
/home/deploy/apps/lcv011/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:117:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/home/deploy/apps/lcv011/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in`instance_eval'
/home/deploy/apps/lcv011/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
/home/deploy/apps/lcv011/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in`block in run_load_hooks'
/home/deploy/apps/lcv011/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
/home/deploy/apps/lcv011/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in`run_load_hooks'
/home/deploy/apps/lcv011/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:316:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
/home/deploy/apps/lcv011/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:26:in`'
/home/deploy/apps/lcv011/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/orm/active_record.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/deploy/apps/lcv011/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in`require'
/home/deploy/apps/lcv011/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/home/deploy/apps/lcv011/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in`load_dependency'
/home/deploy/apps/lcv011/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/home/deploy/apps/lcv011/releases/20150827023110/config/initializers/devise.rb:23:in`block in '
/home/deploy/apps/lcv011/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise.rb:293:in `setup'
/home/deploy/apps/lcv011/releases/20150827023110/config/initializers/devise.rb:3:in`'
/home/deploy/apps/lcv011/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/home/deploy/apps/lcv011/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in`block in load'
/home/deploy/apps/lcv011/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/home/deploy/apps/lcv011/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in`load'
/home/deploy/apps/lcv011/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
/home/deploy/apps/lcv011/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in`instrument'
/home/deploy/apps/lcv011/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
/home/deploy/apps/lcv011/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in`block (2 levels) in '
/home/deploy/apps/lcv011/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
/home/deploy/apps/lcv011/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in`block in '
/home/deploy/apps/lcv011/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/home/deploy/apps/lcv011/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in`run'
/home/deploy/apps/lcv011/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/home/deploy/apps/lcv011/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in`each'
/home/deploy/apps/lcv011/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
/home/deploy/apps/lcv011/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in`run_initializers'
/home/deploy/apps/lcv011/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
/home/deploy/apps/lcv011/releases/20150827023110/config/environment.rb:5:in`'
/home/deploy/apps/lcv011/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/home/deploy/apps/lcv011/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in`block in require'
/home/deploy/apps/lcv011/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/home/deploy/apps/lcv011/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in`require'
/home/deploy/apps/lcv011/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
/home/deploy/apps/lcv011/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:457:in`block in run_tasks_blocks'
/home/deploy/apps/lcv011/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in define'
Tasks: TOP => environment

Any help would be much appreciated!